# apply over matrix by column - any way to get column name?

Tags: r

I'm calling `apply(data, 2, function(x) {...})` where `data` is a matrix.  Is there any way for the function to know the name of the column whose values are present in `x`?  Or perhaps there's another function to accomplish the same task?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One common way to deal with this is to loop over the column names themselves:

```
m <- matrix(runif(16),4,4)
colnames(m) <- letters[1:4]
sapply(colnames(m),function(x){mean(m[,x])})
        a         b         c         d 
0.4720319 0.4992337 0.5026318 0.3514267
```

Comment: Bah, beat me by 5 seconds!  When will I learn... answer first, then edit. ;-)

Comment: Would `sapply(colnames(m),function(x, data){mean(data[,x])}, m)` be slightly better as it explicitly passes data into the function?

Answer (score 19):

You can use `sapply` on `colnames(data)`:

```
set.seed(21)
Data <- matrix(rnorm(10),5,2)
colnames(Data) <- c("one","two")
sapply(colnames(Data), function(x) sum(Data[,x]))
#       one       two 
#  3.987540 -2.010875 
colSums(Data)
#       one       two 
#  3.987540 -2.010875
```