# R sapply name to graph x axis

Tags: r, graph, sapply

I'm using this function to get some exploratory analysis in r

```
nums <- sapply(db, is.numeric)
sapply(db[,nums], function(x) {
  nome <- as.character(names(x))
  hist(x)
  lines(density(x, na.rm = T))

  })
```

How can i print the name of the column in the plot as x axis?
I've tried with [apply over matrix by column - any way to get column name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681013/apply-over-matrix-by-column-any-way-to-get-column-name) but I can't figure out the second part of the function to make it work in this case

Comment: Can you provide example data for db?

Comment: it's a database with both numeric and factors, so the function which assigns to nums will return a vector with TRUE if numeric and FALSE with factor columns respectively, i'll try to give some data sample

Comment: Paste output of `dput` function with a head of your data.

Comment: I currently can't access the dataset, the iris dataset would be the same since it has both numeric and non numeric variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to loop over the column names:

```
nums <- sapply(db, is.numeric)
numsNames <- names(db)[nums]

sapply(numsNames, function(x) {
  hist(db[,x], xlab=x)
  lines(density(db[,x], na.rm = T))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use mapply to take the data and other arguments to hist

```
num <- sapply(iris, is.numeric)
opar <- par(mfrow = c(2,2))
histDensity <- function(x, ...){
  hist(x = x, freq = FALSE, ...)
  lines(density(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}
mapply(histDensity, x = iris[, num], main = names(iris[, num]))
par(opar)
```

Alternatively, you could use ggplot

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
iris2 <- melt(iris)
ggplot(iris2, aes(x = value, y = ..density..)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```